# Is it possible to define a type representing a function with one parameter without 'any' in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics

Obviously, this is fairly trivial using the `any` keyword:

```js
type SingleParamFunction = (arg: any) => any;

const foo: SingleParamFunction = (x: number): number => x + 1;
```

I've tried the following:

```js
type SingleParamFunction = (arg: unknown) => unknown;

const foo: SingleParamFunction = (x: number): number => x + 1;
```

However, the compiler complains that 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.

I'm curious as to whether it is possible to do so without resorting to `any`, perhaps a solution using generics.

---

A potential use case might look something like the following:

```js
interface Foo<I, O> {
    input: I;
    transform: (x: I) => O;
}
const foos: Foo<any, any>[] = [
    {
        input: 1,
        transform: (x: number) => x + 1,
    },
    {
        input: 'hello',
        transform: (s: string) => s + ' world',
    },
];
for (const foo of foos) {
    console.log(foo.transform(foo.input));
}
```

Comment: Function parameters are contravariant, so it would have to be `(arg: never) => unknown` to be sound. `any` is intentionally unsound and that's why it works.  TS lacks [existential types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) so there's no straightforward way to use generics.  Depending on the use case, you could encode such a thing, but what is the point?  If all I know about a function is "it takes one argument", then I can never actually call it because I don't know what type argument it expects... which is why you get `never` there. Could you elaborate on the use case here?

Comment: @jcalz I've added a basic example of what something like this might be used for.

Comment: Sure, but the type you’re asking for wouldn’t support that use case, because there would be no way to call `foo.transform(foo.input)` safely.  Do you want this question to ask primarily about supporting the “array of pairs of functions and their inputs” case?  Or is that example just illustrative?  I’m trying to figure out if the answer should focus on the use case or the original question.

Comment: Why not use a generic like this: `type SingleParamFunction<T> = (arg: T) => T;

const foo: SingleParamFunction<number> = (x) => x + 1;`?

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions to your problem that are equally valid but progressively enhance the type safety.

The first one is the trivial case you presented: `(x: any) => any`. Despite the "never use any" rule of thumb, a judgemental use of `any` can be a valid choice. If all you need is to tell the compiler that the function accepts a single argument of *any type*, then why not?

The second one is more sound and was already proposed by [fjc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3599151/fjc) in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67118835/is-it-possible-to-define-a-type-representing-a-function-with-one-parameter-witho#comment118659616_67118835):

> Why not use a generic like this: type SingleParamFunction = (arg: T) => T;  const foo: SingleParamFunction = (x) => x + 1;?

This solves the contravariance issue, but the compiler will complain about the signatures of the `transform` methods because the union will be passed through, so the `x` and the return type will be inferred as a union (for example, `string | number`):

```ts
interface Foo<I> {
    input: I;
    transform: SingleParamFunction<I>;
}
const foos: Foo<string | number>[] = [
    {
        input: 1,
        transform: (x) => x + 1, //Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
    },
    {
        input: 'hello',
        transform: (s: string) => s + ' world', //Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    },
];
for (const foo of foos) {
    console.log(foo.transform(foo.input));
}
```

This is, however, not the solution's problem. Because `foos` is typed as a mutable array, the compiler does not know what the type of `input` or `transform`'s `x` and return type in a given member is, only that it should be `string | number`.

If you remove the type annotation, you will see, however, that the type of the array is correctly inferred. This should give you a hint of what you need to check for and leads us to a third solution:

```ts
({
    input: number;
    transform: (x: number) => number;
} | {
    input: string;
    transform: (s: string) => string;
})[]
```

So, how would you do it? Mapped types to the rescue! You need to define an "array of Foo's where for each type in possible `input` types there possibly is a member that is a `Foo` of this type". Here is how such a type could look like (with a help of [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as)):

```ts
type validator<I> = Array<{ [T in I as number]: Foo<T> }[number]>;
```

And voila:

```ts
//all ok, valid assignment
const bars: validator<string | number> = [
    {
        input: 1,
        transform: (x: number) => x + 1
    },
    {
        input: 'hello',
        transform: (s: string) => s + ' world'
    },
];

const invalid : validator<string|number> = [
    {
        input: "nope", //Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
        transform: (x: number) => x + 1
    },
    {
        input: 'hello',
        transform: (s: string) => Infinity //Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
    }, 
];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=47&ssc=3&pln=38&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgOwOYBsIAUCGAnTBbAMQFcEBjYOAewQB4AVAPigF4oAKHJALijoEoWTOgG4oUALAAoKaWoBnYFABmlSj3jI0WXIRLkqtBETwAjCNias2ADwHMm1qAGooARmFSpiYOaWZS0ASqNACSTADeUmJiiGBEwDwhHpLRUMC4CHIq2HjqiKgYOPjEZBTUoQzJAL6ekrKZiiqUcjxBlDQK2PlQAD5QRqbmDADaALosUMNR0ZEpqdGx8TyuADTT82kZWZQ5PDY8A2bYdg7OblAA9Bd04NAA5J35d1Bwcv2UiphycnBICJgmNBpShpW5QO6Hcx3AB0bAATABmOFwvjrKBVNZzMSzDYxBBxBLggAWEBQKEod0xuM2mEy2Vy7BaUEeyBOzLOzwA7jsUAATZ5XG6QcGQ7DPV7vT7fX7-QHQYAg0DCh7pJ6wxHI1FY9GY0bJKTZdj1BTKVRQShKU3NAQ46LGyhoaHkpBsJrQ9K07Y5V2qaGLYB8PjVWpK6AAN0wKDgvMwCuwFQmAEFsLgQDRwpM6C8EFAQlAvv1jEdRq1gox0cNRaNKrVjYoTDgmRGozG4x1VcheoXBhYJlNtbaNv7llTcR66TsGftu0c2Y4XK40Ri0YP5sPiaTyZS0alx16p0yWUg2W8XFyefyl7r9XV5IpEM3o1AeI-Wzt211kD1RZZJiudws%20JLFAABECCUJAIErJc1xgiqn5IOKbzgVKPx-ACQIKqCyqijC8JIiiAFiHu9J7NYBxFuYc5nIu2rLgORHZgSPB3CSZIUqOGwkZOeyHh2x6CLmCBKIgcCgDBQr3LhLzIR8%20bSuhcrAth9xHnhGqEXR0FSHqQA)